# Enforce RFC 7230 Validation for Apex RestResponse Headers - Need to understand

Tags: apex, apexrest, header, release-update

I am analysing the impact of the salesforce release update "Enforce RFC 7230 Validation for Apex RestResponse Headers". In our org's apex class logic, we have

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/GET_ACC/*')
global class AccountDetails {
    @HttpGet
    global static void getData() { 
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String paramURL = req.requestURI;
        String accId   = paramURL.substringAfterLast('/');
        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        .......
```

}

Here we are using 'Content-Type' as 'application/json' in the addHeader method.
I tried to verify if this is valid format in the RFC 7230 document provided by Salesforce. But this documenation on RFC7230 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-9 seems very difficult to understand.
Could anyone please guide me how to find the valid headers and please let me know if this header is RFC 7230 compliant or not.

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer to the very same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr:

Based on my reading of [the relevant help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_enforce_RFC_header_validation.htm&release=244&type=5) and the RFC itself, `res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` should be fine. It should be valid according to RFC 7230 (section 3.2)

As long as your header name is:

- US ASCII
- doesn't include `"`, `(`, `)`, `,`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`,`>`, `?`, `@`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `{`, or `}` or a whitespace

then it should be fine.

Header values (e.g. `application/json`) should be able to contain `/`; Salesforce is just talking about the header name when saying that `/` is not allowed.

### Longer version

RFC-7230 is a large document. Salesforce is specifically referring to [section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2). I.e. pages 23-27.

The language that Salesforce uses suggests that they're only checking the header name (e.g. "Content-Type") and not the header value (e.g. "application/json")

Section 3.2 uses a variation (Augmented Backus-Naur Form) of pretty standard notation (Backus-Naur Form) to describe the syntax of things. If you've gone through a Computer Science program at a college/university, you almost certainly have encountered BNF before.

> ```
> header-field   = field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS
>
> field-name     = token
> field-value    = *( field-content / obs-fold )
> field-content  = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB ) field-vchar ]
> field-vchar    = VCHAR / obs-text
> ```

So the header name corresponds to a "field-name", and a "field-name" is comprised of a "token".
What's a token?
section 3.2.6 clarifies

> ```
> token          = 1*tchar
>
> tchar          = "!" / "#" / "$" / "%" / "&" / "'" / "*"
>                / "+" / "-" / "." / "^" / "_" / "`" / "|" / "~"
>                / DIGIT / ALPHA
>                ; any VCHAR, except delimiters
> ```
>
> A string of text is parsed as a single value if it is quoted using
> double-quote marks.
>
> ```
> quoted-string  = DQUOTE *( qdtext / quoted-pair ) DQUOTE
> qdtext         = HTAB / SP /%x21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E / obs-text
> ```

the `1*` bit just means "this thing can be repeated 1 or more times". I.e. "A token is a sequence of 1 or more characters".

`Content-Type` is valid because `-` is allowed as a "tchar", and everything else falls into the `ALPHA` category (which is just shorthand for a-z and A-Z)

If Salesforce is extending validation to the OWS (optional whitespace) field-value as well...
field-value is any number of field-content
field-content is a field-vchar, optionally followed by 1 or more spaces/tabs and another field-vchar
and a field-vchar is a VCHAR (short for visible ASCII character)

`application/json` is a sequence of visible ASCII characters, so it should be valid as a header value.

Comment: Thank You for your detailed answer. I also tested it by enabling the security update in a sandbox and it works fine with "content-type" as "application/json" passed in the header value.

Comment: @Derek F Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.